# in javascript / jquery how can i parse a string (with inconsistence spaces) into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, parsing

i have a string that looks like this:

```
1, 2, 4, 4,5, 6
```

NOTE: notice the inconsistency in spaces

what is the best way to convert this to an array of integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var s = '1, 2, 4,    4,5, 6  ';
var o = s.trim().split(/ *, */);
```

([Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/2mb7A/)) Trimming first (may not be necessary), then splitting on comma (`,`), discarding all spaces ().

---

**UPDATE**
Casting to integer using jQuery to iterate ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/2mb7A/2/)):

```
var s = '1, 2, 4,    4,5, 6  ';
var a = s.trim().split(/ *, */);
var o = $.map(a, function(elm) {
    return parseInt(elm, 10);
});
```

*Note: A simple `for` loop could have been used instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/2mb7A/3/)):*

```
var s = '1, 2, 4,    4,5, 6  ';
var a = s.trim().split(/ *, */);
var o = [];
for (i = 0, j = a.length; i < j; i++) {
    o.push(parseInt(a[i], 10));
};
```

Comment: is there anything i need to do to indicate these are integers (instead of strings) ??

Comment: @ooo Oh, sorry, didn't read that part of the question. That would require an iteration over the array (e.g., `jQuery.map()`) and a cast (e.g., `parseInt(?, 10)` or `1 * ?`). See updated answer.

Comment: Instead of `parseInt(n, 10)` you could’ve just used `Number(n)`.

Comment: Alternative to `.trim().split(/ *, */);` is `.match(/\d+/g);`, cf. @meouw's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As Regular Expressions seem to be quite popular in the answers submitted so far I thought I'd add a couple of RexExp based solutions

If you *really* need integers:

```
var str = '1, 2, 4,    4,5, 6  ';
var arr = [];

str.replace( /\d+/g, function( i ) {
    arr.push( parseInt( i, 10 ) );
});

console.log( arr ); //[1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

If strings will do

```
var str = '1, 2, 4,    4,5, 6  ';

var arr = str.match( /\d+/g );

console.log( arr ) //["1", "2", "4", "4", "5", "6"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`var arr = str.split(/,\s*/);`

Comment: After running this against OP’s suggested input, you’ll see `arr === ["1", "2", "4", "4", "5", "6    "]`. You’ll need to trim at least the first and last numbers. Also, OP asked for an array of integers (numbers), not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var inputStr = "1, 2, 4, 4,5, 6 ";
    var arrInput = inputStr.split(",");
    var arrOutput = new Array();
    for(var ctr in arrInput){
       arrOutput[ctr] = parseInt(arrInput[ctr].replace(" ",""));
    }
```

Comment: Do **not** use `for...in` to iterate over numerically-indexed arrays.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [];
var string = "1, 2, 4, 4,5, 6  ";
$(string.replace(/\s+/g, "").split(",")).each(function() {
    array.push(parseInt(this));
});

return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey, just to round out the offerings... the quickest way to convert a numeric string to number is the unary operator +. e.g.

```
var nums = ' 1, 2, 4, 4,5, 6 '.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').split(/\D+/);
var i = nums.length;
while (i--) {
  nums[i] = +nums[i]; 
}
```

You could also use:

```
nums[i] = nums[i] | 0;
```

You may be better off to convert them to numbers when you use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str= '1, 2, 4, 4,5, 6  ';
var integerarray= str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
```